# Node JS - Data of my html form isn't updated to SQL with req.body but instead sends out "undefined"

Tags: html, sql, mysql, node.js

I'm building my first CRUD application (Create, Read, Update, and Delete), but i'm having issues Updating the Data.

On the html page, when you click on a table row that you wish to update, it sends you to an update page with a form where you can change the elements and submit the data with a button ; then it console.log the value of what has been changed.

The problem is that it console.logs "undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined" instead of something like "1 Ricardio Ricardio@gmail.com password1234 18yearsold", and the data isn't updated to my SQL table (named calipplpush1)

I'm new with node js and mysql, so i will do my best to provide you with a detailed answer if you have questions.
I suspect this might be a problem with the req.body.id, req.body.exercice etc

This is the route for my update page (server.js) :

```
app.get('/update', function(req, res){  // Table Update page
    var sql = `Select * from calipplpush1 where id =?;`
    var id = req.query.id;
    con.query(sql,[id],function(error,result){
        if (error) console.log(error);
        res.render('update',{ calipplpush1: result});
    })
});
```

This is the Post to update the data (server.js)

```
// Post Table Update to the database
app.post('/updateData', function(req, res){
    var id = req.body.id;
    var exercice = req.body.exercice;
    var sets = req.body.sets;
    var repetitions = req.body.repetitions;
    var kilograms = req.body.kilograms;
    console.log(id, exercice, sets, repetitions, kilograms);
    var sql=`update calipplpush1 set exercice=?, sets=?, repetitions=?, kilograms=? where id=?`
    con.query(sql,[id,exercice,sets,repetitions,kilograms], function(error,result){
        if (error) console.log(error);
        console.log("Data Updated");
        res.redirect('/cali-ppl')
    })
})
```

This line :
console.log(id, exercice, sets, repetitions, kilograms);
--> it sends "undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined", and there is no update on my html or sql database.

This is my update.ejs file with the form to update :

```
<div class="div_table_update">
    <table class="table">
        <form method="POST" action="/updateData">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="caliPush1Id"  placeholder="id" class="workout_data_input" value="<%= calipplpush1[0].id %>" readonly/>
            </td>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="caliPush1Ex"  placeholder="exercice" class="workout_data_input" value="<%= calipplpush1[0].exercice %>"/>
                </td>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="caliPush1Sets" placeholder="sets" class="workout_data_input" value="<%= calipplpush1[0].sets %>"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="caliPush1Reps" placeholder="reps" class="workout_data_input" value="<%= calipplpush1[0].repetitions %>"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="caliPush1Kgs" placeholder="kgs" class="workout_data_input" value="<%= calipplpush1[0].kilograms %>"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" class="workout_data_btn" value="ok" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried to replace the "ID" primary column to select from the database with the "exercice" column, but it still shows "undefined".

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `undefined` because req.body is empty object `{}`. To use req.body, you would have to parse it first. In order to do that, use this middleware:

```js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

or use express's built-in parser:

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should have been more clear as i forgot to tell that i'm pretty confident that the issue lies within the lines of code i've shown. I already have the body parser

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you already have added the body parser in your code. So the problem must be the way you are sending the post request. When sending post request, you should keep in mind the encoding type of the request.

- If you are using a `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` then you should use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
- If you are using a `app.use(bodyParser.json();` then you should use `multipart/form-data`.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

*Please note that this may not be correct because I usually don't work with ExpressJS.*

## Edit

I just now realised this while looking at your code.
In your server's code, you are trying to get these:

```js
var id = req.body.id;
var exercice = req.body.exercice;
var sets = req.body.sets;
var repetitions = req.body.repetitions;
var kilograms = req.body.kilograms;
```

but in your HTML code, you are having input fields with names `caliPush1Id`, `caliPush1Ex`, `caliPush1Sets`, `caliPush1Reps`, and `caliPush1Kgs` .

Names are for the server to understand what data belongs to which field. So with that being said, your server code should look something like this

```js
// Post Table Update to the database
app.post('/updateData', function(req, res){
    var id = req.body.caliPush1Id;
    var exercice = req.body.caliPush1Ex;
    var sets = req.body.caliPush1Sets;
    var repetitions = req.body.caliPush1Reps;
    var kilograms = req.body.caliPush1Kgs;
    console.log(id, exercice, sets, repetitions, kilograms);
    var sql=`update calipplpush1 set exercice=?, sets=?, repetitions=?, kilograms=? where id=?`
    con.query(sql,[id,exercice,sets,repetitions,kilograms], function(error,result){
        if (error) console.log(error);
        console.log("Data Updated");
        res.redirect('/cali-ppl')
    })
})
```

I hope that helped you. If you find a correct answer, consider marking it as correct. This helps others to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `console.log(req.body)` you should see that your data is there, but under different field names. The name of each field will be the name you gave the field in the html, in your case:

- req.body.caliPush1Id
- req.body.caliPush1Ex
- req.body.caliPush1Sets
  etc.